# How to use Scala defined function in Cassandra interpreter on Zeppelin Notebook?

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-zeppelin

I have the next function defined on Zeppelin notebook:

```
import java.util.Date

def timeFormat(d: Long) : String = {
    val l = (d * 1000).toLong
    val time = new Date(l)
    time.toString()
}
```

Using it for a single item:

```
timeFormat(1471887281116L)
res2: String = Thu Apr 02 10:05:16 UTC 48612
```

And now I want to format some timestamps from cassandra using:

```
%cassandra
select timeFormat(timestamp) as time from keyspace.table;
```

Without the function the query return some result but with it the output is:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException:
    Unknown function 'timeformat'
```

In [Zeppelin tutorial](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/quickstart/tutorial.html), it shows how to [get and format](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/quickstart/tutorial.html#data-retrieval-1) data using functions, concretely registering the function with:

```
sqlc.udf.register("functionName", functionName _)
```

which allows us to access it from %sql interpreter, but I wonder how to do it on %cassandra interpreter.